# Is there any better way to set function to react hooks useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I wanted to setState with react hooks usestate.

First I tried. but it not worked.

```
const [action, setAction] = useState(null);
...
<button onClick={()=>{
  setAction(()=>{console.log('hi')})
}}>test</button>
```

Second. It worked.

```
const [action, setAction] = useState({action: null});
...
<button onClick={()=>{
  setAction({
    action:()=>{
      console.log('hi')
    }
  })}
}>test</button>
```

Because if I set function directly, the state changed to undefined.

So I pass the function with object type.

But I want to know if there is another way to set state with function.

Comment: please don't use reserve functions like useState and state try changing it to some other names

Comment: @SinanYaman I need function state variable because, I should change action on a button by some other changes. Is this appropriate answer with your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your approach is that you are not returning the function in the first place. you are just using the `setAction` callback to `console.log('hi')`.

```
<button onClick={()=>{
  setAction(()=>{console.log('hi')})
}} />
```

To fix this issue you need to return a new function in the callback function.

```
<button onClick={()=>{
  setAction(() => () => {console.log('hi')})
}} />
```

Comment: Wrapping in a function was the solution for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is `useRef`, not `useState`...!

As [documented](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), if you passed a function to `useState`, it will set the state to the `value` it gets `after executing` the passed function...!

So `setAction(()=>{console.log('hi')})` means set the `action` state to the result of executing this function `()=>{console.log('hi')}`, that gives you `undefined` (because `()=>{console.log('hi')}` returns nothing).

If you need to store a function, maybe try this...?

```
import { useRef } from 'react'

// ... other code

const functionRef = useRef(null)

<button
  onClick={() => functionRef.current = () => console.log('hi')}
/>

// ...
```

Comment: The reason for the not working was because of the document`s useState which gets after executing when it passed function parameter. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `<button />`, it should be `<button></button>`. [Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samgermain/06qgLp41/5/) where your code is working

```js
const useState = React.useState;

const App = () => {

    const [action, setAction] = useState(null);

    return (
      <button onClick={()=>{
            setAction(()=>{console.log('hi')})
        }}>Click me!</button>

    );

}

const render = () => ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);

render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```